# How to improve speed of the following integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate an energy functional in a 3D space to obtain a stiffness matrix. But the integral is very slow. Does anyone know how make it faster?

Here is the code:

```
   EqElast =
 {Elast == mu (2 mu + 3. lambda)/(mu + lambda), 
  poisson == lambda/(2 ( mu + lambda))}
sollambda = Solve[EqElast, {mu, lambda}][[1]]
Elasticidade = {Elast -> 25 10^9, poisson -> 0.2}
DeslocGeneric = 
  Flatten[Table[x^i y^j z^k, {i, 0., 2.}, {j, 0., 2.}, {k, 0., 2.}]];
Deslocx = 
  Table[{DeslocGeneric[[i]], 0., 0.}, {i, 1, Length[DeslocGeneric]}];
Deslocy = 
  Table[{0., DeslocGeneric[[i]], 0.}, {i, 1, Length[DeslocGeneric]}];
Deslocz = 
  Table[{0., 0., DeslocGeneric[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[DeslocGeneric]}];
Desloc = Join[Deslocx, Deslocy, Deslocz]
Length[Desloc]
For[i = Length[Desloc], i >= 1, i--,
 If[(Desloc[[i, 1]] /. x -> 0) != 0, Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i], , 
  Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i] ];
 If[(Desloc[[i, 2]] /. y -> 0) != 0, Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i], , 
  Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i] ];
 If[(Desloc[[i, 3]] /. z -> 0) != 0, Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i], , 
  Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i] ]
 ]
(* Este trecho impoe condicoes de engastamento no pilar *)

For[i = Length[Desloc], i >= 1, i--,
 If[(Desloc[[i, 1]] /. z -> 0) != 0, Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i], , 
  Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i] ];
 If[(Desloc[[i, 2]] /. z -> 0) != 0, Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i], , 
  Desloc = Delete[Desloc, i] ]
 ]
GradDesloc = 
  Table[Transpose[{D[Desloc[[i]], x], D[Desloc[[i]], y], 
     D[Desloc[[i]], z]}], {i, 1, Length[Desloc]}];
Deform = Table[(GradDesloc[[i]] + Transpose[GradDesloc[[i]]])/2, {i, 
    1, Length[GradDesloc]}];
TensorTensao = 
  Table[lambda Tr[Deform[[i]]] IdentityMatrix[3] + 
    2 mu Deform[[i]], {i, 1, Length[Deform]}];
Energia = 
  Table[ Tr[Deform[[i]].TensorTensao[[j]] ], {i, 1, 
      Length[Deform]}, {j, 1, Length[Deform]}] /. sollambda /. 
   Elasticidade;
VolumeLoad = Table[{0, 0, -2000.}.Desloc[[i]], {i, 1, Length[Desloc]}];
FaceLoad = 
  Table[{0, 0, -100.}.Desloc[[i]] /. z -> 50, {i, 1, Length[Deform]}];
Rigidez = 
  Table[Integrate[
    Energia[[i, j]], {x, -0.25, 0.25}, {y, -0.25, 0.25}, {z, 0., 
     50.}], {i, 1, Length[Energia]}, {j, 1, Length[Energia]}];
```

Comment: The definition of `Energia` is missing.

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer i have edited includind the energy definition.

Comment: (1) Use below to avoid decimal exponents. `DeslocGeneric = 
  Flatten[Table[x^i y^j z^k, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0,2}, {k, 0, 2}]];` (2) Use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`.

Comment: `Energia` has a lot of repeated expressions, so memoization helps a lot. see here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html